# How can I make two different components the same height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react card that can render two different things depending on a whether or not a certain prop is active. How can I ensure that the two different things are the same height, as the cards are not the same size when I put them next to each other?

Here is the code:
`<div className={cardInfoClasses}>
  <h3 className={titleClasses}>{this.props.name}</h3>
  {cardMain}
</div>`

cardMain can either be:
`<div>
  <Progress productData={productData} className='mobile_hide'/>
</div>;` or
`<CardButton initialData = {this.props.data}/>`

Comment: Can we see some example code?

Comment: In order for us to help with your coding problem, you will need to actually **show** us your code. Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: sorry, added the code if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with display flex or table. You give the parent display flex and adjust other properties like justify-elements and width.